# Retrieve an ASP.NET cookie without the [key]= part

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have an ASP.NET cookie that I set like this:

```
string identifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
HttpCookie dateCookie = new HttpCookie("identifier");
dateCookie.Values.Add("identifier", identifier);
dateCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
Response.Cookies.Add(dateCookie);
```

Then I retrieve it like this:

```
string cookievalue = Request.Cookies["identifier"].Value;
```

cookievalue now has this value:

```
identifier=79976995-468a-4ff0-b259-9686c487f9d5
```

How do I retrieve the cookie so that I only get:

```
79976995-468a-4ff0-b259-9686c487f9d5
```

Comment: Use `Split` method.`Split('=')[1]` will give you `79976995-468a-4ff0-b259-9686c487f9d5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string strcookie=cookievalue.Split('=')[1];
```

[Split MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx)

Hope you understand and it works for you.